# How to handle promise and non-promise error catching together

Tags: javascript, promise

I am executing an array of functions, each of which may return a promise and may return a value. When handling the return value, I want to be able to catch all errors created by the selected function regardless of it being a promise or value. Here's an example of what I wish to accomplish:

```js
const functionA = (v) => {
throw "Value error"
}
const functionB = (v) => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  throw 'Promise error';
})

const functionsArray = [functionA,functionB]
  .map(f=>Promise.resolve(f())) // run function and cast return as promise
  .map(f=>f.catch(console.log)) //add error catching
```

I know I can wrap the function execution in a try/catch block but I would prefer to have a single error catching segment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.then()` catches synchronous errors:

```
const functionsArray = [functionA, functionB]
  .map(f => Promise.resolve().then(f))
```

There’s a proposal to call this [`Promise.try`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-try).

An async function will also do the trick:

```
const functionsArray = [functionA, functionB]
  .map(async f => f())
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! If I want to pass a value to f(), how would I use the first approach? f=>Promise.resolve().then(f("val")) will still not catch the exception.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out:
f=>Promise.resolve("val").then(f)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Promise.all`. as @Ry- pointed out its easy to convert the functions to promise using the `async` keyword on the map, so your code should look like:

`Promise.all([functionA,functionB].map(async f=>f())).catch(console.log)`

Comment: The problem is, I want to catch and resume for the individual functions. So yes, Promise.all will catch if any error happens, but it will also prevent the rest of the functions from executing. I suppose I didn't explain that intent in my question though.